# How do I connect satellite receivers for live streaming?

Tags: linux

I want to create a live stream from a satellite receiver.
The output available is RCA audio/video.
How can I use it and connect to PC so that I can stream?
Any specific hardware for Linux?

Answer (score 0):

if your videocar has an video-in connection you may use that, else try to buy an converter/adapter.

What you can do also, if you have the money, buy an sattelite reciever which has usb support or dvi/vga/hdmi, these can be linked to the pc if you have the correct hardware.

I think an usb sattelite reciever would be your best bet.

EDIT:
Added this comment:

I noticed it's RCA, I think this would be your all-in-one solution:

http://www.trianglecables.com/usb20-videograbber.html

There are (I think) no linux drivers but you could use a windows emulator or some wrapper for the DLL's.

(Windows Emulator would be you easiest option as the software will run on it too)

Comment: thanks gam, i can get reciever with hdmi also but they question is how to input hdmi to PC... USB sat reciever is not able to serve all purpose. If i use HDMI how can i caputure and stream it to VLC?

Comment: I noticed it's RCA, I think this would be your all-in-one solution:
http://www.trianglecables.com/usb20-videograbber.html There are (I think) No linux drivers but you could use a windows emulator or some wrapper for the DLL's. (Windows Emulator would be you easiest option as the software will run on it too)